# Spring Boot Hibernate and JSR 303 - response formatting

Tags: java, validation, spring, spring-mvc

Sifting through forums I can't seem to stumble into an issue solution I've been haveing with Spring Boot + JPA and JSR303 bean validation.

Simply put validation works but but when say

```
org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException
```

is thrown and then the output a consumer gets (from a rest controller) is something like this:

```
"timestamp": 1427658793929,
"status": 400,
"error": "Bad Request",
"exception": "org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException",
"message": "Validation failed for argument at index 1 in method: public org.springframework.http.HttpEntity<org.springframework.hateoas.Resource<org.home.project.UserInfo>>... {omitted for brevity}
```

This is overkill verbosity - can I intercept this to make the "message:" part of JSON more formatted and user friendly (e.g.) produce a simple list saying:

```
>  - "messages:" { "firstName can not be Empty or Null or has to be at least 8 characters", 
"lastName is a swear word...", ... }
```

Comment: how does the constraint look like?

Comment: Basically this tutorial has answered my question - http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-from-the-trenches-adding-validation-to-a-rest-api/